# how can i use navigation drawer in api level 8

Tags: navigation, drawer

I have used navigation drawer in my app which is currentlu running on min api level 14, I want to run it on min api level 8 as wel, Kindly give some solution

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this

https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer

or here which is practically the same

http://codingandroidapps.blogspot.com/2013/05/navigation-drawer-and-actionbarsherlock.html